# jQuery - Hide a div menu after clicking outside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've build a drop down menu at:

http://www.ourbridalsongs.com/new_header/header.php

When you click on the up/down arrow next to the logo - the menu appears - I'd like to make it disappear when clicking anywhere else on the screen - for some reason it's getting stuck and doesn't slide back up.

Can anyone help resolve this!

Here's my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>");
    $("ul.topnav li span").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('slow').show();
        $(this).parent().click(function () {}, function () {
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow');
        });
    }).hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("subhover");
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("subhover");
    });

});
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this snippet in your code

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    var myTarget = $(".subnav");
    var clicked = e.target.className;
    if($.trim(myTarget) != '') {
        if($("." + myTarget) != clicked) {
            $("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

this will close your `ul.subnav` when you click anywhere in your document.

Answer (score 29):

It's quite simple: bind a function that hides that menu to everything except that menu. To do that bind a *click* listener to the `body` element as it's everywhere, also bind a *click* listener to menu - the last one should just prevent from executing the first one.

```
$("body").click(function() {
    $("#services-container-id").hide();
});

$("#services-container-id").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I think you would want to do $("body > *").click(... to get all the children of the body.

Comment: I didn't want to get children of `body`. I wanted to get `body` itself.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine! The magic is the stopPropagation which will prevent a click on the service container to reach the body.click event.

Comment: Incredibly simple solution. I've seen many solutions here in SO but this one is different because it's easier to understand for beginners and provides easy control over the items you want to hide and the items you want to exclude from the action (stop propagating the click). **AND** it's still a relevant solution after this long. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks I also tried many proposals and this is the simplest one that I fond works wonderful for me !!!

Comment: Could someone please elaborate on binding functions? Primarily, I presume one binds a function to the body tag via onClick but what would I put in onClick(). Similarly, How would I bind to my navigation menu?

Comment: I think this answer doesn't properly explain the real meat of the solution, which is `e.stopPropagation()`. What this is doing is preventing a click on the menu element from bubbling up the DOM and eventually triggering the click event  on `body`.