# 'Underlying' div to capture 'outside' events

Tags: jquery, click, modal-dialog

I have a question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321239/event-on-a-click-everywhere-on-the-page-outside-of-the-specific-div) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544134/jquery-hide-a-div-menu-after-clicking-outside-div). I have a menu that appears on top of other content on a button-click. I want the menu to close if the user clicks anywhere outside the menu. There is lots of other 'stuff' that could be clickable while the menu is up - I want any click to just close my menu. In effect, I want the menu to be modal, still be able to see what's behind it, and any outside click closes it without activating the thing you clicked on.

I've created a absolute-positioned div with z-order just below the menu container div. The 'underlying' div has a click event to close the menu. When the underlying div has a background color so I can see it, everything works great. But I want this underlying div to be transparent. When I remove the background color, it no longer gets the click event!

Answers to the linked question suggested adding a click event to the body or document itself to close the menu, but I don't really want to do that becuase the menu won't be up all the time. Plus, once it's down, there's no need to capture clicks.

What do I need to do to the 'underlying' div to make it transparent but still capture the click event?

**EDIT:** What seems to work but makes little sense is this:

1. Style the underlying div to have a background color.
2. In jQuery, set its opacity to 0.

Now the div is transparent and captures events. ???

Comment: is this a problem in all browsers or just ie? http://coilmedia.com/post/2010/can-not-click-or-hover-transparent-links-elements-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transparent background lets the background elements click through, by changing it to opacity of 0 your still clicking on the background.  It'd be the same as adding a 1x1 clear .gif or .png and tiling it on the background - it's allowing for something to be clickable

Edited to include the link from the comment - it exactly describes my problem: [link](http://coilmedia.com/post/2010/can-not-click-or-hover-transparent-links-elements-in-internet-explorer/).

Thanks!

Comment: That certainly semes to be the behavior - thanks for confirming it!

Comment: to make it more clear (no pun intended) a background of transparent is to say there is no background rather than a background you can see through

Comment: Thanks. The leap I didn't make was that also meant it was 'transparent' to events. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. What I did was create an array called `needsClickInfo` and every time a button click was registered on the screen, it would call the objects/functions stored in `needsClickInfo`. Of course, you would have to update `needsClickInfo` in the `onMouseEnter()` and the `onMouseLeave()` functions of the object/element you are dealing with, in this case, a menu bar.