# jQuery bind on callback fires itself

Tags: jquery, callback, event-handling

I have a menu that shows on click of a certain element, and what I want to do on its callback is bind a click event to the body so that you can click anywhere to make the menu hide (and then subsequently unbind that new binding).

```
$('#menu_button').click(function(){
    $('#user_menu').toggle();
}, function(){
    $('body').bind('click', function(){
          if($('#user_menu').css('display') == 'block')
                $('#user_menu').hide();
    }, function(){
          $('body').unbind('click');
    }); 
});
```

The problem is that it doesn't just bind the click on body, but it fires that event too. I tried wrapping that binding in setTimout to add delay, but the body click event that was just bound ends up firing (and the menu never shows, bummer). Is there a better way of handling this case?

Comment: I don't remember an extact solution to this problem, but you should check out .blur() function, also event.stopPropogate() (event bubbling). Other things that you can do is to check what element trigger the event using .contains()

Comment: Also look at the `one()` method (http://api.jquery.com/one/).  It will fire once and then automatically unbind itself.

Comment: Thanks Pete, that'll clean things up! I tried blur(), it works when clicking on the #user_menu div itself, but not on the rest of the document. e.stopPropagation() didn't seem to help.

Edit: What I thought was achieved with blur was happening already. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done this way :

```
$('#menu_button').click(function () {
    $('#user_menu').toggle(function(){
        $("body").bind("click",function(){
            $('#user_menu').hide();
            $("body").unbind("click");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yup that does it, thanks! In my case I learned that the button itself wasn't as simple as just being one element, it's like, 4 different elements that need to be checked (I blame the intern haha). So the answer I posted I think might make more sense rather than binding a bunch of elements, but if I refactor I'll definitely go with this option.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with the answer to my problem, based on this response: [jQuery - Hide a div menu after clicking outside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544134/jquery-hide-a-div-menu-after-clicking-outside-div)

My solution is a bit different, it goes like this:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    var clicked = e.target.id;
    if(clicked != 'menu_button') {
        $('#user_menu').hide();
    }
});
```

Simple as that lol. I wasn't aware of .target before, definitely will remember that one.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I'm not sure if I understand your problem or not. My question is: why using the .bind() method?
For something like you, I usually do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu_button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('#user_menu').show();

    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
      if( $('#user_menu').has(e.target).length === 0 ) {
        $('#user_menu').hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/m2ry2ajn/1/

Comment: That's more or less the same solution that I have, replacing a string comparison with '.has()' - as I mentioned in a comment to thecbuilder,  the button itself is comprised of a few elements (not my mistake), but when I get around to refactoring it/making a single element, either your solution or thecbuilder's solution will work fine (although his is a bit more concise which I prefer). Thanks though!